# Google KickStart question displaying "WA" even after giving correct outputs

Tags: python

Problem

There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend.

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

Limits

- Time limit: 15 seconds per test set.
- Memory limit: 1GB.
- 1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
- 1 ≤ B ≤ 105.
- 1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, for all i.

Test set 1

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 100.

Test set 2

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 105.

Sample

Input

```
3
4 100
20 90 40 90
4 50
30 30 10 10
3 300
999 999 999
```

Output

```
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 0
```

This was my first attempt at a google coding problem:

```
t = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(t):
    inp = input()
    lis = []
    lis = inp.split()

    inp1 = input()
    lis1 = []
    lis1 = inp1.split()

    total = 0
    number_of_houses = 0

    lis2 = sorted(lis1)

    for j in range(int(lis[0])):
        total += int(lis2[j])
        if int(lis[1]) >= total:
            number_of_houses += 1

    arr.append(number_of_houses)
for i in range(t):
print("Case #" + str(i+1) +": " + str(arr[i]))
```

Are there any rules for the way we write our code
that I should be aware of?

Comment: You need to sort the list of prices after conversion to int, not before

Comment: Once I sorted the list of prices before the conversion to int, it worked. Thank You